# Push notification in android using SignalR

Tags: android, push-notification, signalr

I am working on an android application and basically, I want to send a push notification when the user is connected to a local server as well as when connected to the internet.

I see SignalR as an option, but as I am new to this, I want to know can signalR be used to send Push notification like FCM? Also, can it work if the user is offline and receive it when he comes online or gets connected to the local server?